# Caching a large stream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on a streaming application, which I am caching a large RDD (that is only in memory)..

```
Dstream.cache()
Dstream.foreachRDD(..)
Dstream.foreachRDD(..)
```

I wanted to know if the Dstream can not be fit into the memory..Is the RDD recomputed or raise an exception?

I am asking this question since I am developing a stateful application using mapwithState function which internally uses an internal stream which is presisted only in memory.(https://github.com/wliuxad/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/MapWithStateDStream.scala#L109-109)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which RDD we're talking about. `MapWithStateDStream` caches the data inside a `OpenHashMapBasedStateMap`. It doesn't spill to disk. This means that you need to have sufficient memory in order for your application to work properly. When you think about it, how can you evict state? It isn't some RDD that is being persisted, *it is part of your application logic*.

One thing that *is evicted* is the cached `RDD` from your source. From your previous example I see that you're using Kafka, so that means that the cached `KafkaRDD` will be evicted once Spark sees fit.